# Graphic type column in ebcidic table db2

Tags: db2, mainframe

Can I define columns of type graphic and vargraphic in a table created on ebcdic tablespace ? Platform is zOS db2. Facing sqlcode -879. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a whole bunch of z/OS DB2 documentation. What did you discover? Did you look up the message for that SQLCODE? https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.codes/src/tpc/n879.dita "Programmer response Contact your system administrator to properly set up the installation options, or change the data types of the elements in columns in your CREATE or ALTER statement."

Comment: Yeah , I looked up there Bill and told our system administrator to check MIXED DATA settings.Thanks